# How to restore backup of Oracle Database unto same server where original database is running (and not allowed to shutdown original database)

Tags: oracle, rman, oracle-19c

I'm using RMAN, it's Oracle 19c and non-CDB (stand-alone). The problem is that the restored database has to have a different name, since the original database is already running on that server. However, if you rename the database in the `init.ora` file before `STARTUP MOUNT`, the controlfile and `init.ora` files will have different database names and the database will error out trying to start up.

Comment: Are you using RMAN to backup the original database? What version and architecture (stand-alone, CDB / PDB) are you using?

Comment: @pmdba, I'm using RMAN, it's Oracle 19c and non-cdb (stand-alone). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the RMAN `duplicate` command? This is basically what it is designed to do. You can duplicate from either a live running instance or from an RMAN backupset. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/rman-duplicating-databases.html#GUID-F31F9FCE-B610-49EB-B9DB-44B9AA4E838F

Comment: @pmdba, thanks for you comment...the document is clear on how to duplicate from "host1" to "hosts2", but can't find where it explains how to duplicate to same host (will have to rename database "on the fly")

Comment: There's an example for local host duplication. target database name is given as a parameter to the duplicate command: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/bradv/rman-duplicating-databases.html#GUID-E9A97E86-8E83-4205-B76E-6AD013CEFDED